# Wait in background while webdriver work

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, java-threads

I have a problem with Selenium WebDriver
The fact is that I want run wait error's message in background, while I test my page, but it should not affect the total test's time

for example I tried:

```
 private void checkHeaderError(){
        String errFieldXpath = "path";
        ScheduledExecutorService executor=Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
        Runnable task = () -> {
            try {
                new WebDriverWait(getWebDriver(), 0).until(
ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(errFieldXpath)));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                String errMsg = getWebDriver().findElement(By.xpath(errFieldXpath)).getText();
                Assert.fail(errMsg));
            }
        };
        executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(task, 0, 4, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
```

but it doesn't work
Honestly, I do not even know where to put it so that it works

Comment: I am not sure webdriver is designed for parallel use. I'm afraid (since you're using the same instance of a driver in different thread) you will either not get the actual parlallelisation or just break the logic of your tests since I cannot guarantee that all that api is thread-safe.

Comment: thanks for comment. Unfortunately, I think the same way

Comment: Have you considered using listeners for webdriver?

Comment: Hi, Mike. No, I have not.
Can you give example or any information?